# I have a 404 error in an Ajax call on Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, http-status-code-404

I'm pretty new to ajax (and web development in general) and I'm trying to implement this code directly on my view:

```
<% content_for :after_js do %>
<script type="text/javascript">

    //1st dropdown selection
    const dropdownOne = document.querySelector('#order_credits_package_id');

    //Listening to dropdown change
    dropdownOne.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      const selectedPackage = event.target.value
      console.log(selectedPackage)
      // document.getElementById("order_amount_centavos").value = event.target.value

      // Params for AJAX call
      const url = "/dynamic_dropdown_method";
      const data = {'selection': selectedPackage }

      // Storage of AJAX call answer (NB: can be refactored to avoid 2 calls)
      // the ['id'] must match the one defined in your controller
      const level_1_selected = ajaxCall(url, data)['dropdown_1_selected'];
      const level_2_array = ajaxCall(url, data)['dropdown_2_array'];

      // Identification of 2nd dropdown
      const dropdownTwo = document.querySelector('#order_amount_centavos');

      // Delete and replace options in 2nd dropdown
      removeOptions(dropdownTwo);
      addOptions(level_2_array, dropdownTwo)
    });

  // AJAX call
  function ajaxCall(url,data) {
    var result = "";
    console.log("call Ajax")
    console.log(url)
    console.log(data)
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      success: function (response) {
        console.log("ajax Call")
        console.log(response)
        result = response;
      }
    });
    return result;
  }

    // Delete existing select options
    function removeOptions(selectElement) {
      console.log("fonction remove")
       var i, L = selectElement.options.length - 1;
       for(i = L; i >= 0; i--) {
          selectElement.remove(i);
       }
    }

    // Add select option
    function addOptions(optionsArray, dropdown) {
      optionsArray.forEach(function (item) {
        const new_option = document.createElement('option');
        new_option.value = item;
        new_option.innerHTML = item;
        dropdown.appendChild(new_option);
        });
    }
  </script>
<% end %>
```

I then added this method to the controller related to this view:

```
def dynamic_dropdown_method
    @selection = params[:credits_package_id]
    @array_dropdown_2 = CreditsPackage.find(@selection).price_centavos
    return render json: {level_1_selected: @selection, level_2_array: @array_dropdown_2}.to_json
end
```

And the following route:

```
post "/dynamic_dropdown_method", to: "orders#dynamic_dropdown_method", as: :dynamic_dropdown_method
```

But when I try to run my code, I get the following error message in the console:

POST http://localhost:3000/dynamic_dropdown_method 404 (Not Found)

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure that `params[:credits_package_id]` isn't `nil`?

Comment: Actually, I'm not, because I can't even get to that part because of the routing error :/

Comment: What does `rake routes` give you?

Comment: dynamic_dropdown_method POST     /dynamic_dropdown_method(.:format)                            orders#dynamic_dropdown_method